# Pandas: concatenating empty df with existing df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two df:

- historical df: which is empty with only 5 columns: `["count_date", "device", "hour", "count", "average_speed"]`
- result df: which has 38688 rows and 5 columns (sames ones as historical df)

When I'm trying to concatenate them:

```
historical_df = pd.concat(["historical_df", "result"], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

I've checked and both df are DataFrame types.

Any idea where it could come from? Is there something I'm missing?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `pd.concat(["historical_df", "result"]` vs `pd.concat([historical_df, result]` : see the difference? ;)

Comment: I'm so dumb, thank you for noticing me this mistake ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct apart from one minute detail:
According to the official [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) of pandas.concat we have:

> objs: a sequence or mapping of Series or DataFrame objects

In other words, the first parameter ought to be a list of pandas DataFrames; not a list of strings. In your code this would mean:

```
historical_df = pd.concat([historical_df, result], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Note that I simply removed the quotes for the strings.

Here is a dummy code that will produce the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd

# create an empty dataframe with column names
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['count_date', 'device', 'hour', 'count', 'average_speed'])

# create an existing dataframe
historical_df = pd.DataFrame({'count_date': ['2023-05-09', '2023-05-10'], 
                            'device': ['A', 'B'], 
                            'hour': [8, 9],
                            'count': [100, 200],
                            'average_speed': [50.0, 60.0]})

# concatenate result with historical_df
historical_df = pd.concat([result, historical_df])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
ListMyDfs = ['df_1', 'df_2', 'df_3']
 
df = pd.DataFrame()
 
for MyDf in ListMyDfs:
   if not globals()[MyDf].empty:
        df = pd.concat([df, globals()[MyDf]], axis=0)
```